# Regex to match a word, even is there are spaces between letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'd like to have a regex to match a word, even if there are spaces between the characters.
When I want to match the word `test`, it should match the following:

`test
t est
t e s t`

And so on, but it should not match things like this:

`tste
te ts
s tet`

I have this regex:
`(t[\s]*e[\s]*s[\s]*t[\s]*)` 
But I don't believe that this one is very efficient.

Comment: remove the character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way to match such words. You have to consume these spaces, otherwise you won't have a match. Actually, your pattern is the same as

```php
t\s*e\s*s\s*t
```

If the word appears inside a larger string, you can consider a word boundary version:

```php
\bt\s*e\s*s\s*t\b
```

**NOTE**: If only one whitespace is allowed in between each letter, you can use `?` quantifier instead of `*`:

```php
t\s?e\s?s\s?t
```

Comment: So there's no better way to do this?

Comment: Well, you might replace all spaces with empty string before matching. BUT you will lose word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Why not remove all horizontal spaces from input and then match regex:

```
$input = 't e s t';
$regex = '/\btest\b/i';

preg_match($regex, preg_replace('/\h+/', '', $input), $m);
```

Comment: In some cases this would be acceptable solution but what if you have to know the length of your match. 
e.g. 
`test me for length` must return 'test' sou you can know the match length is 4
but `t e s t me for length` must return 't e s t' so you can know the length is 7.

If you remove the spaces you lose that info and you can only test your search string existance but you can't do length calculation with the match since both will be 4.